Sentry flutter source maps missing stack traces and missing_source_content error
I have a problem with Sentry for Flutter. I can't read stack traces and I have a missing_source_content error.
pubspec.yaml config:
sentry:
  upload_debug_symbols: true
  upload_source_maps: true
  upload_sources: true
  project: myapp-cms
  org: myorg
  web_build_path: ../shopify/web/frontend/simulator

flutter commands:
fvm flutter build web --source-maps --base-href "/simulator/" --output "../shopify/web/frontend/simulator"
fvm flutter packages pub run sentry_dart_plugin

Sentry init:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final nodeEnv = _getNodeEnv();
  final isReactAppInDevMode = nodeEnv == 'development';
  final isReleaseMode = !kDebugMode && !isReactAppInDevMode;

  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) => _configureSentry(options, isReleaseMode),
    appRunner: () => _run(isReleaseMode),
  );
}

void _configureSentry(SentryFlutterOptions options, bool useSentry) {
  options.dsn = useSentry ? BuildConfig.sentryDsn : '';
  options.environment = useSentry ? BuildConfig.sentryEnvironment : '';
  options.beforeSend = (SentryEvent event, Hint hint) {
    final exceptions = event.exceptions?.map((exception) {
      final stackTrace = exception.stackTrace;
      if (stackTrace != null) {
        final frames = stackTrace.frames.map((frame) {
          const baseUrl = 'https://myapp.run.app/';
          final modifiedAbsPath = frame.absPath?.replaceFirst(baseUrl, '${baseUrl}simulator/');
          return frame.copyWith(absPath: modifiedAbsPath);
        }).toList();
        return exception.copyWith(stackTrace: SentryStackTrace(frames: frames));
      }
      return exception;
    }).toList();
    return event.copyWith(exceptions: exceptions ?? []);
  };
}

My app is hosted in the simulator subdirectory: https://myapp.run.app/simulator/, that's why I have options.beforeSend in my init function.


